# function that takes a vector and returns negative numbers and position

Tags: matlab, function, vector

I'm looking to create a function that will take a vector and return all the negative values in one vector and their position in another vector. So, for example,

```
% output:
v = [-1 4 6 2 -3]

% output:
vneg = [-1 -3]
pos  = [1 5].
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution to get the negative values and their index.

```
x = [4 3 -2 9 -7 31];

index = find(x<0);
-> index = 3 5

x_new = x(index);
-> x_new = -2 -7
```

Just change the condition in the find function as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks for the help but how can i write this in a function? I believe I need to use loops

Comment: You need to study a bit. Learn what find() function does in matlab. You will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete @WasiAhmad's answer:

```
function [vneg, pos] = find_negatives(V)

    pos  = find(V < 0);
    vneg = V(pos);

end
```